# Run .js every minute or every 45 seconds?

Tags: node.js

My js is located at `/home/ubuntu/bot/setup/node bot.js`i would like to know how to run this js file every 45 seconds or one minute at least.

Comment: You can run it every minute with [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I'd recommend cron as well, although some people are preferring [systemd Timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Timers). I've found them to be a lot less intuitive than cron though. Be careful of anything you're running that frequently though. If it causes high CPU usage, you're likely to have a bad time with it running once a minute.

Comment: yeah, i mean what if the script takes longer than 45 seconds? Implement some sort of lock

Comment: It's probably a lot more efficient from the system point of view to just create a function in bot.js that you call in a `setTimeout()` repeated timer rather than restarting the process every minute.  Then, if you use repeated `setTimeout()`, you can schedule the next run only when the first once has finished and thus handle the case where it takes a long time to turn.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with cron. Here is a place to start https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. 
You can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), and install [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to run it while your computer/service is running. 
Or you can just use 
 `setInterval( function () {
   call();
}, 45000);` 
And run it with node, or forever module.

Comment: In where do i need to put the
setInterval( function () {
   call();
}, 45000); 
?

Comment: in your file, for example, in your file run.js wrap it all in a function then call the function inside the setInterval ( function () { yourFunction(); }, 45000);